# ContentPlaceholder in aspx files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I need the equivalent of a ContentPlaceholder in an ASPX file (as opposed to a Master page). I don't want to use a dedicated [WebControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) descendant (TextBox, Label, etc), because using those forces me to use server-side forms, and I don't like that (VS pollutes the HTML with all sorts of crap when I do that).

So, what control should I use in ASPX files if I only need to inject a simple HTML fragment that's rendered in the code behind at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer, with assistance from Mortuus who helped locate the namespace I had to look into: I'm using [PlaceHolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [ContentPlaceHolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.contentplaceholder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) – that's all there is to it. ContentPlaceHolder is for Master pages, PlaceHolder is for ASPX pages, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a page like so:

```
<body>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" id="htmlPlaceholder"></asp:Literal>
</body>
```

You can assign HTML text to the label, which will be rendered as actual HTML, with a code file similar to the one below:

```
protected void Page_Load(...)
{
    htmlPlaceholder.Text = @"<div>Content</div><br /><div>etc...</div>
}
```

Comment: That's a good start, but I want to add an HTML fragment, not HTML as a text. Unfortunately the Literal control doesn't allow children...

i.e. I want to be able to write something like htmlPlaceholder.Controls.Add(myControl)